# Network Scans Find Absent Device

Tags: dns, nmap, nessus, administration

Using Nessus (an uncredentialed full scan) and Nmap (essentially a full port scan), I am finding a phantom device. This device is supposed to be a well-out-of-commission device, but is returning a computer name when responding to its old IP address. There are no ports found from Nmap. I have asked the guy to look through his DNS records in case there's an old entry for this thing, but I'm not sure what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try a `nmap -Pn -p 0-65535` scan against the host. The device may not report any ports because it is not responding to pings. Also, is the dns entry there when you perform a nslookup? What happens when you `ping -a` the phantom device? Can you track the location to a subnet specific to a switch and then look at the stats on the switch? What does the DNS server say about the hostname or address in question?

I don't think you have done enough enumeration.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry i was actually using nmap -Pn -p 0-9099,9101-65535 and got this result.  I'll get the info off the switch too.  thanks for that .